# How can I achieve a 2 column layout that switches between fluid and fixed divs?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

When the window is resized, Column A should shrink its width up to 50 pixels, but Column B should remain at a fixed width . After 50 pixels are removed from Column A, it should become fixed, and then Column B should then begin shrink (unlimited).

[image: Two column layout]

Within the HTML code, A should come before B. The divs need to be in the order because of the requirements I need with responsive design.

```
<div id="ColumnA"></div>
<div id="ColumnB"></div>
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: What is the max width that you are starting at?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with CSS2.1, probably you will have to use CSS3 flexbox.

Comment: So, you start at 1140, then shrink. As you are shrinking, Col A shrinks by 50px, then becomes fixed, at which point Col B stops being fixed and starts shrinking. What are both initial sizes?

Comment: @AndyM Yes. Initial size for A should be 300px and B should be 820px. A should shrink to 250px and then become fixed, after which B starts shrinking (unlimited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, and to help my js I put together this little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/H7ebg/1/) that does what you want with js.

JS

```
var startleftwidth   = 150;
var leftwidth        = 150;
var minleftwidth     = 101;
var startrightwidth  = 420;
var rightwidth       = 420;
var startwindowwidth = $(window).width();
var difference       = 0;

$(window).resize(function(){
  difference = $(window).width() - startwindowwidth;
  leftwidth  = startleftwidth + difference;
  if (leftwidth < minleftwidth)
     {
      setleftwidth(100);
      newrightwidth = rightwidth + difference + (startleftwidth - minleftwidth);
      setrightwidth(newrightwidth);
      }
       else
     {
      setleftwidth(leftwidth);
      setrightwidth(startrightwidth);
      }
  if (leftwidth > startleftwidth)
     {
      setleftwidth(startleftwidth);
      }
});

function setleftwidth(leftsize)
{
 $('.leftdiv').css('width', leftsize); 
}

function setrightwidth(rightsize)
{
 $('.rightdiv').css('width', rightsize); 
}
```